# how to add prefix json string in golang

Tags: json, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am newbie. I have a `image` in my db which is `stored as a path` to it. In api json I have to output this path and add a `prefix` in front of it, how can I do that?
My function:

```
func GetAllSliders(c *gin.Context) {
    var sliders models.Slider

    config.DB.Model(models.Slider{}).Where("id=?", 1).Update("image", ("https://spares-dt.ru/" + models.Slider{}.Image)) //i tried this, but it doesnt work

    if err := config.DB.Find(&sliders).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": sliders})
    }
}
```

Json output i have:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "main_text": "123",
        "upper_text": "123",
        "down_text": "123",
        "image": "data/photos/sliders/image.PNG"
    }
}
```

I want:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "main_text": "123",
        "upper_text": "123",
        "down_text": "123",
        "image": "https://spakes-dt.ru/data/photos/sliders/image.PNG"
    }
}
```

And my struct:

```
type Slider struct {
    Id        uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    MainText  string `json:"main_text"`
    UpperText string `json:"upper_text"`
    DownText  string `json:"down_text"`
    Image     string `json:"image"`
}
```

Comment: Simply update the `image` field in Go before calling `c.JSON()`, something like `sliders.Image = "https://spares-dt.ru/" + sliders.Image`. And take the [Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1) if you're not familiar with Go's basics.

Comment: @icza Thanks for your answer, I also tried this way but it didn't help. Instead of the desired output, it simply outputs ```"data/photos/sliders/image.PNG"```

Comment: Then please post how `models.Slider` looks like and the exact code you tried.

Comment: As written in my previous comment, `sliders.Image = "https://spares-dt.ru/" + sliders.Image` followed by `c.JSON()` should do it. You're still not showing us something.

Comment: @icza I'm sorry I didn't paste your answer correctly, now it's working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the `Image` field's value before JSON marshaling it:

```
if err := config.DB.Find(&sliders).Error; err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
} else {
    sliders.Image = "https://spares-dt.ru/" + sliders.Image
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": sliders})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how custom json marshalling works. Modifying your model by adding the MarshalJson method will help you to customize.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Slider struct {
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    MainText  string `json:"main_text"`
    UpperText string `json:"upper_text"`
    DownText  string `json:"down_text"`
    Image     string `json:"image"`
}

//Add MarshalJson function
func (u *Slider) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        ID        int    `json:"id"`
        MainText  string `json:"main_text"`
        UpperText string `json:"upper_text"`
        DownText  string `json:"down_text"`
        Image     string `json:"image"`
    }{
        ID:        u.ID,
        MainText:  u.MainText,
        UpperText: u.UpperText,
        DownText:  u.DownText,
        Image:     "https://spakes-dt.ru/" + u.Image,
    })
}

func main() {
    data := Slider{Image: "data/photos/sliders/image.PNG"}
    bdata, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println(string(bdata))
}
```

This will produce the following output.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "main_text": "",
  "upper_text": "",
  "down_text": "",
  "image": "data/photos/sliders/image.PNG"
}
```

Update your code something like this after you create MarshalJson method

```
func GetAllSliders(c *gin.Context) {
    var sliders models.Slider

    config.DB.Model(models.Slider{}).Where("id=?", 1)//i tried this, but it doesnt work

    if err := config.DB.Find(&sliders).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    } else {
        b, _  := json.Marshal(sliders)
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": string(b)})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use exec

```
config.DB.Exec(`UPDATE slider SET image = "https://spares-dt.ru/" + iamge WHERE id = ?`, 1)
```